# Change hovered dropdown content-Bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using Bulma and I made an hoverable dropdown, but the dropdown content exceeds the whole page content. How can I make it fixed with larger width and also responsive?

For now it looks like this:
[image]

Html code:

```
 <div class="navbar-end">
<div class="dropdown is-hoverable navbar-item ">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button aria-controls="dropdown-menu6" aria-haspopup="true" class="button is-primary">
      <strong>Account</strong>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu has-text-centered" id="dropdown-menu6" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        <p>Acces your quizbee account, test your skills and have fun. </p>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        <div class="buttons is-centered">
          <button class="button is-primary is-rounded">Register</button>
          <button class="button is-light is-rounded">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add your CSS here

Comment: I use Bulma predefined css classes. I don't use custom css.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set a position of dropdown. Add class **`is-right`**

```
<div class="dropdown is-right is-active">
```

Comment: I tried that before but "is-right"  works only for desktop. For smaller screens the dropdown content is pushed to the left so you can't see the entire content.